# Why doesn't the ternary syntax work in this situation?

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

This is valid:

```
def prime? n
  (2...n).each {|num| return false if n % num == 0 }
  true
end
```

This is ***NOT*** valid

```
def prime? n
  (2...n).each {|num| n % num == 0 ? return false : true }
end
```

Aren't these both *saying* the same thing? Why does the second example cause a syntax error?

---

Now why does this next example work in the `ternary` syntax?

```
def primes max
  primes_arr = []
  (2...max).map { |num| prime?(num) ? primes_arr << num : next }
  primes_arr
end
```

Comment: Don't think of ternary operators as a control structure, which is how you are attempting to use it.  Ternary operators are for _returning_ or _assigning_ values.  You're trying to do the operation `primes_arr << num` in the place where the positive assignment should be. What you'll get instead is probably the boolean result

Comment: @majioa why does that work? Now you just blew my mind.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that example that you are referring too is actually working properly. The middle example is the one which is not.

Comment: Also look into to .all? method of arrays and enumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code cause a syntax error because the *ruby* interpreter don't know, where the arguments for `return` keyword has end up, the correct example is:

```
def prime? n
   (2...n).each {|num| n % num == 0 ? ( return false ) : true }
end
```

Here is the `next` isn't really required just use boolean logic:

```
def primes max
   primes_arr = []
   (2...max).map { |num| prime?(num) && primes_arr << num }
   primes_arr
end
```

If we do some optimization, we can do:

```
def prime? n
   (2...n).all? {|num| n % num != 0 }
end

def primes max
   (2...max).select {|num| prime?(num) }
end
```

Next level of optimization shell be this:

```
def primes max
   (2...max).select {|num| (2...num).all? {|num1| num % num1 != 0 } }
end
primes 7
# => [2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: why even use return keyword at all?

Comment: I'm still not understanding. Can you please elaborate. I will surely accept your answer

Comment: And this is kind of an abuse of the operator. :)

Comment: This is a perfect case for `Enumerable#any?`

Comment: @feed_me_code It's just that (not to put words in sergio's mouth) the ternary means _"if this condition is true, give me this value, otherwise give me that value"_ It is not a direct replacement or shorthand for the logical `if`, as in "_if this condition is true, perform this action, otherwise perform a different action"_

Comment: @feed_me_code what exactly you didn't understand? the ruby interpreter don't know which argument you shell to pass to it. You shell help him,  just put the parentheses.

Comment: @majioa, I think your "next level" example is stylish but not incorporating the `prime?` method isn't DRY --- Even still +1

Comment: @feed_me_code sorry, i;ve just optimized the whole code you've supplied =)

Comment: @majioa Though all answers were great -- I find yours most insightful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Adding parenthesis to explicitly state the way Ruby is interpreting what you have:

```
(2...n).each { |num| (n % num == 0 ? return false) : true }
```

We can verify this in that we get the same error message with and without the parenthesis:

> SyntaxError: (eval):2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_false, expecting ':'

You can solve this by giving explicit parenthesis to force Ruby to interpret it how you want:

```
(2...n).each { |num| n % num == 0 ? (return false) : true }
```

Or you can only return false when the case is met (as you have in your question). Or, better yet, use `any?` instead:

```
(2...n).any? { |num| n % num != 0 }
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. Just fyi, your last example is invalid -- it should be `(2...n).all? {|num| n % num != 0 }`

Comment: +1 for parenthesis. Language compilers and interpreters are not smart enough to read our minds so parenthesis give them the necessary hints to do things right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proper usage of ternary operator (no operator at all :) )

```
def prime? n
  !(2...n).any? {|num| n % num == 0 }
  # or
  # (2...n).all? {|num| n % num != 0 }
end

(1..10).each do |x|
  puts "prime?(#{x}) \# => #{prime?(x)}"
end
# >> prime?(1) # => true
# >> prime?(2) # => true
# >> prime?(3) # => true
# >> prime?(4) # => false
# >> prime?(5) # => true
# >> prime?(6) # => false
# >> prime?(7) # => true
# >> prime?(8) # => false
# >> prime?(9) # => false
# >> prime?(10) # => false
```

Comment: So enumerable `all?` just has a baked in false:true return? That's interesting. And Sergio, you never commented if you think majioa's code smells?

Comment: @feed_me_code `all?/any?` is good methods to implement logic as you wish

Comment: @sergio - I'm sorry to tell you but your code had bug. Does not evaluate primes properly. Rerun with larger int.

Comment: @feed_me_code I said "abuse" because ternary operator is not meant to be used as a control structure. It should be used as an expression.

Comment: @Sergio I think this cleaner and less confusing `(2...n).all? {|num| n % num != 0 }` than the negation of `any?`